# sysprep Windows 7 not generating a random name

Tags: windows-7, windows, sysprep, unattended

I am attempting to deploy a number of Win 7 instances (a mix of both 32- and 64-bit) all using Win 7 Enterprise.  I'm using the Windows AIK to generate an unattend file.

I followed the guide [here](http://theitbros.com/sysprep-a-windows-7-machine-start-to-finish-v2/) for the most part.  Reading [other places](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749460(v=ws.10).aspx) online I had come to believe that if I set the `<ComputerName>` value to `*` that would cause Windows to generate a random computer name when it came up.  I also tried with that being an empty string: `<ComputerName></ComputerName>` but had the same results of being prompted.

I seem, so far, to be unable to get it to ever respect that field in my unattend file.  Whether I put `*` or some other string like `test_name` it always comes up and prompts me for the computer name, and always defaults to `PC`.

Here is my unattend.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="generalize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SkipRearm>8</SkipRearm>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <RunSynchronous>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>1</Order>
                    <Path>net user administrator /active:yes</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
            </RunSynchronous>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SkipAutoActivation>true</SkipAutoActivation>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ComputerName>*</ComputerName>
            <CopyProfile>true</CopyProfile>
            <TimeZone>Eastern Standard Time</TimeZone>
            <ShowWindowsLive>false</ShowWindowsLive>
            <ProductKey>REDACTED</ProductKey>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-UnattendedJoin" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Identification>
                <UnsecureJoin>true</UnsecureJoin>
                <JoinDomain>corp.local</JoinDomain>
            </Identification>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <InputLocale>en-us</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-us</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-us</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>en-us</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <UserAccounts>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Password>
                            <Value>REDACTED</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Description>Local Admin</Description>
                        <DisplayName>Local Admin</DisplayName>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                        <Name>ladmin</Name>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <NetworkLocation>Other</NetworkLocation>
                <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
            </OOBE>
            <RegisteredOrganization>GTRI</RegisteredOrganization>
            <RegisteredOwner>ACTR</RegisteredOwner>
            <TimeZone>Eastern Standard Time</TimeZone>
            <ShowWindowsLive>false</ShowWindowsLive>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="catalog:d:/sources/install_windows 7 enterprise.clg" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

I also tried a stripped down unattend file that I was hoping would only set the computer name, but it also did not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ComputerName>*</ComputerName>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="catalog:d:/sources/install_windows 7 enterprise.clg" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

So what am I missing?  (Also, the joining to the domain step doesn't seem to be working yet so I may have an error there too, but I haven't tried troubleshooting that symptom yet.)

To use the above file I am running:

```
sysprep /oobe /shutdown /unattend:unattend.xml
```

Comment: `<ComputerName>*</ComputerName>` there a reason you currently have it set to just have a wild card character?  Anyways you should verify `RegisteredOrganization` and `RegisteredOwner` is in the current location in the configuration xml file

Comment: @Ramhound According to [this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749460(v=ws.10).aspx) an asterisk should trigger it to generate a random name, though an empty string should do it too apparently, I'll try that too

Comment: @Ramhound With `<ComputerName></ComputerName>` it still has the same behavior

Comment: You have `RegisteredOrganization` and [`RegisteredOwner`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766241(v=ws.10).aspx) in an invalid section of your configuration file/

Comment: @Ramhound well that's a surprise. . . I think I only tried setting them in a desparate hope to influence the name, but all of those came from the AIK tool.  I'll just remove them

Comment: You need to place them in the correct section (Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup) not remove them.  Your random name is generated from those two values.

Comment: @Ramhound no change, and the link you provided says that they are acceptable (at least RegisteredOwner) in the `oobeSystem` section, which is where they are right now, I can try them in the `specialization` section though

Comment: I am reading the documentation entirely different.  It indicates to me that it's parent hierarchy should be `Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup` but you are able to pass those valid settings to that component.  You also have two of the same component which likely is your actual problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63871/discussion-between-eric-renouf-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 0):

Specify also the RegisteredOwner and RegisteredOrganization in the Windows-shell-setup section of the specialize pass.

Also, realize that you cannot deploy the same image to multiple machines without also specifying the /generalize switch in sysprep. This resets SIDs.

Finally, realize that this is a 32-bit unattend file you showed. There is a different one required for 64-bit OS.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.  Unfortunately, if I change the RegisteredOrganization and RegisteredOwner in the specialize pass it says it cannot process the unattend file.  That's a great point about the `/generalize` though, I'll definitely need that.  And good catch about the 32/64 bit, though I do need both and have been trying the 32 first.  Embarrassingly, I think I might have stumbled on the problem though and it seems to be trying to use a different, and apparently wrong, product key.  If I changed only that, the name part started just working